# How to include custom directory when building gRPC dotnet core project with MSBuild

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I have a dotnet core gRPC project and I'm trying to include route annotations in my proto files like below:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

file structure is like this (for the reason being that I imported `googleapis` repository as a git submodule):

```
protos/
    myproto.proto

    googleapis/
        google/
           api/
               annotations.proto
               ...
```

in a go project it can be done by:

```
protoc -I . -I ./googleapis --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

where `-I ./googleapis` gives compiler the dir where it can find `annotations.proto` file and its dependencies.

But when I'm using MSBuild in a dotnet grpc project using config like below, I could not figure out how to include custom directories.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="protos/*.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[Official doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md) mentioned an alternative to customize target build so that I can use `protoc`:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(gRPC_PluginFullPath)  -I $(Protobuf_StandardImportsPath) ...
```

but above command ignores service definition and does not generate server stub code as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated), while MSBuild does.

A workaround I found but not ideal:

I realize `Grpc.Tools` dotnet package distributes some commonly used proto files, so I copied `annotations.proto` and its dependencies there (in macOS) and it worked:

```
`~\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.25.0\build\native\include`
```

Updates:

Another workaround:

The project root directory is included by default, so use it as the base path and copy the imported proto files there also works (better but still not ideal).

Any ideas how to include custom directories like above through MSBuild?

Comment: You're probably missing some grpc-specific options in your custom command: e.g. `--grpc_out=OUT_DIR`

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the ProtoRoot="protoc" in msbuild and make sure all your .proto files are under that directory (with subdirectories corresponding to the package names). In your case, you'd have `protos/myproto.proto` and `protos/google/api/annotations.proto` (without the "googleapis" directory because "google/api" needs to corresponds to the namespace of annotations.proto) and everything should build just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally figured out. As [Jan Tattermusch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5454771/jan-tattermusch) suggested, `ProtoRoot` specifies the directories from which msbuild `Include` property as well as the proto `import` keyword will be looking for files, whereas the way `ProtoRoot` works for `Include` is different from how it works for `import`. Thus in order to customize the proto file structures to be like this, `ProtoRoot` must include all different paths which should be:

```
<Protobuf Include="protos/*.proto" ProtoRoot="./protos; ./protos/googleapis" ... />
```

**Updates**:

Above works fine for grpc-dotnet version prior to v2.31.0. For newer versions, [warnings](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23852) will show up saying `ProtoRoot` path is not a prefix of `Include` path. To fix it, use below config instead:

```
<Protobuf Include="protos/*.proto" ProtoRoot="protos" AdditionalImportDirs="protos/googleapis" ... />
```